# Probability of observed data in HMM

Tags: machine-learning, probability

In a given Gaussian mixture model with observed continues variables $Y$ and latent discrete variables $X$ I want to apply the forward-backward algorithm in order to compute the marginal posteriors $P(x_t|y_{1:T})$.

Since this is computed as $$\frac{\alpha_t(x_t) \beta_t(x_t)}{P(Y)}$$

I was wondering how do I obtain the value of $P(Y)$? The only probabilities I have given is a transition probability $P(x'|x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your notation correctly, the answer is as follows.

You can find probabilities $P(x_t=k|y_{1:T})$ from this equation:
$\sum_{k=1}^K P(x_t=i|y_{1:T}) = 1$, here $k \in [1, K]$ - the index of the latent state.

Just use the equation that you stated and you will see that:
$\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\alpha_t(k) \beta_t(k)}{P(Y)} = 1$.

From this you get what you need:
$P(Y) = \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_t(k) \beta_t(k)$.

Hope it will help.